# Почему не выводит ответ в popup?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Подскажите пожалуйста, как из background.js отправить сообщение в popup.js и там его вывести в мое окно? Мне ничего не выводит в окно расширения.

Вот скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`background.js`

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
   url: "hello"
});
```

`popup.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
   document.querySelector('.otvet').innerHTML = request.url;
});
```

`popup.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
   <div class="otvet"></div>
</body>
<script src="popup.js"></script>

</html>
```

`menifest.json`

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "M3U8 Extractor",
   "version": "1.0",
   "permissions": [
      "webRequest",
      "tabs",
      "<all_urls>"
   ],
   "background": {
      "scripts": [
         "background.js"
      ]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   }
}
```